# When doing a redirect, Akamai is redirecting to orignial server, Why?

Tags: http, redirect, cdn, akamai

Please bear with me because I am not very familiar how akamai works.

I am having issues with redirection. We are redirecting links `domain.com/a/b` to `domain.com/c/d`. However, akamai does not respect domain.com and the 301 goes to the original server. To illustrate:

`http://akamai.ex.example.com/a/b`

Redirects to

`http://original.ex.example.com/b/c`

When it is supposed to redirect to

`http://akamai.ex.example.com/a/b`

What is going on and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why, but I can tell you how to work around it:
Path-absolute (or host-relative?) redirect URLs of the form "/b/c" completely bypass the issue, and will make the browser go to the same host (and port, and protocol.)

(There's a typo in the RFC, relative URIs are allowed in the Location header, all browers support it anyway: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/185)

Comment: Thanks, I considered this. But now I know why this is happening. Akamai hostname is pointing to the original server. I am trying to fix it.